# What is the different between these two list comprehension calculations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been running my own statistical analyses, but I'm curious as to why there are different outputs for the following two list comprehensions. I am using Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu LTS 16.04:

Input:

```
example = [[15, 16, 17],
           [18, 19, 20]]

list1 = [item[0] + item[1] + item[2] for item in example]

for item in example:

    list2 = [item[0] + item[1] + item[2]]

list1, list2
```

Output: `([48, 57], [57])`

Clearly the second function is printing the sum of the second row, but why not the first?

Comment: The second example is **not** a list comprehension. You're just repeatedly assigning over the same name.

Comment: Gotcha, I figured it was overwriting somehow, just wasn't sure why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The second example is not a list comprehension, the final list has only one item as you're overwriting `list2` variable with every loop execution.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same output, the second loop should be corrected to this:

```
list2 = []
for item in example:
    list2.append(item[0] + item[1] + item[2])
```

Otherwise you overwrite what you had assigned to `list2` in the previous iteration of the loop, only getting the result of the last iteration.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I did have that in my original code.